# Invalid argument" setting key "net.core.somaxconn"

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, linux-kernel, sysctl

I tried setting Linux kernel. After editing */etc/sysctl.conf* and executing the `sysctl -p`
it shows error

```
Invalid argument" setting key "net.core.somaxconn"
```

Linux distribution:  Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS,  x86_64,  3.2.0-60-generic

```
$ cat /etc/sysctl.conf
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.arp_notify = 1
vm.swappiness = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 4194304
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 16384 4194304
net.core.wmem_default = 8388608
net.core.rmem_default = 8388608
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
net.core.somaxconn = 262144
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 262144
fs.file-max = 1048576
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 30
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 1200
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 409600
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65000
net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans = 262144
```

Can I increase the `net.core.somaxconn`  to `262144`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Same issue I got into when I tried to fine tune my nginx. This is the problem with the patch that been made to Ubuntu kernel.
The

> sk_max_ack_backlog field of the sock structure is defined as unsigned short.

Therefore, the backlog argument in `inet_listen()`
shouldn't exceed `USHRT_MAX`. The backlog argument in the `listen()` syscall is truncated to the `somaxconn` value. **So, the `somaxconn` value shouldn't exceed `65535` (`USHRT_MAX`).**

So in short to make your `net.core.somaxconn` work you should not give value greater then `65535`

> net.core.somaxconn = 65535

This is sad but we have to live with it until unless you are ok to repatch your kernel:
https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kernel-team/2013-October/033041.html